# Alfresco share : document name when downloading pdf rendered version

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

On Alfresco 5.2, after uploading an xlsx ou docx file (for instance), a PDF version of the document is generated.
After that, one can download the document in its original format or its pdf version.

When downloading the original version, the downloaded file will be "filename.extension".
But when doing so with the pdf version, the downloaded file will be "document.pdf"

Is there a way to modify this behaviour so that both ways to download give the real file name ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit odd to have `example.xls` which is actually a PDF?

Comment: I may not have explained things well. For instance, I upload "MyFile.xslx". If I download it in its original format, then the downloaded file will be "MyFile.xslx". But if I download the PDF version, the file will be named "document.pdf". I wish it was named "MyFile.pdf".

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is coded in the web-preview (PdfJs.js) and picks the preview (pdf rendition named pdf.pdf) as it is from the Alfresco repository. Unfortunately there is no easy and update save way to customize this except you write your own Alfresco module replacing/overwriting the whole web-preview javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Heiko :) I'll have to find a workaround. Do you think it would be possible to do it in another way ?

Comment: I'm afraid this will require a rebuild either way since I guess the java script function doesn't know the document's name. You could check by debugging [PdfJs.js](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share/src/main/webapp/components/preview/PdfJs.js). As an upgrade save work around we implemented an independant custom share action retreiving the pdf thru a custom webscript.